# Utilize Azure Graph API for SharePoint Online User management

Tags: api, azure, office365

Let's say I have SharePoint Online subscription, hence I can manage own ***.onmicrosoft.com domain and users/groups connected with it.

As far as I understand, the storage behind SPO where users and groups reside is an Azure AD.

I had a thought that the only way to manage these users/groups remotely is using PowerShell module for Microsoft Online. And now I wounder whether Azure Graph API can be used for purposes of retrieving users and group members from the SPO? I have no Azure subscription, is there a way to utilize Azure Graph API without Azure subscription, having only SPO subscription?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out it is possible. Briefly steps are the following:

1. Create a service principal that will serve as 'contact point' with your external application ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx) is a good start point); I've used symmetric key authorization;
2. Add a newly created service principal to the 'Company Administrator' role;
3. Look at the azurecoder's [article](http://azurecoder.azurewebsites.net/using-windows-azure-active-directory-waad-part-2-graph-api/) and check out his comprehensive example of using Graph API: https://github.com/azurecoder/azure-activedirectory; this code correctly deals with authentication parameters, like constructing proper service realm.

After that I was able to grab users, groups and users membership information for SPO instance without creating a Azure AD subscription.